# Phonegap Geolocation in Android 4.0.4

Tags: android, geolocation, phonegap-plugins, sony

I am developing phonegap based android app and in this, I am not able to get current location's lattitude and longitude for android OS 4.0.4 (I am testing in Sony xperia phone). The code works absolutely fine with other OS versions. What's wrong with this OS? Regards Ashwini.

Comment: What version of PhoneGap are you using?

Comment: I am using 2.0.0 version and tried with 2.2.0 version also, but still doesn't work.

Comment: Same here, tried on 4.1.2 on Nexus 7, it works :(

Answer (score 0):

If you are bundling with PhoneGap Build Service, are you using a `config.xml` file?

Most importantly the 'config.xml' must have the permission specified like this one:

`<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/geolocation" />`

You can take a look at file that resolved my problem with Android 4.0.4
http://bit.ly/gap-config